# LTO and virtual destructor weirdness c++

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, virtual-destructor, lto

I'm having issues when compiling/Linking with LTO enabled with GCC 4.8.1. I get undefined references to symbols in a DLL even though they seem to be present. The strange thing is, without LTO enabled it compiles and links successfully. LTO seems to struggle when there is a virtual destructor that hasn't been defined in the derived class.

- Removing the DECLSPEC makes it compile and work with LTO enabled.
- Dependency walker shows the symbols are there. The link time optimizer just can't seem to find them.
- Declaring any type of destructor in derived class `Test` makes it work.
- Removing LTO optimization also makes it work successfully, I'm wondering why this is an issue.

Test is a shared library, Main links to the shared library.

Test.h

```
#include <string>

#ifdef SOURCE
    #define DECL __declspec(dllexport)
    #warning Exporting!
#else 
    #define DECL __declspec(dllimport)
    #warning Importing!
#endif

class DECL TestBase
{
public:
    TestBase(const std::string testing);
    virtual ~TestBase();

    std::string getTesting();

private:
    std::string _testing;
};

class DECL Test : public TestBase
{
public:
    Test(const std::string testing);
    //~Test(); //removing causes a linker error with LTO! Fine without LTO.
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

TestBase::TestBase(const std::string testing)
{
    _testing = testing;
}

TestBase::~TestBase()
{
}

std::string TestBase::getTesting()
{
    return _testing;
}

Test::Test(const std::string testing) :
    TestBase(testing)
{
}

/*Test::~Test() //removing causes a linker error with LTO! Fine without LTO.
{
}*/
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Test test("testing!");

    std::cout << test.getTesting() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Excuse my messy makefile..

```
CC=g++
LD=g++

LIBCFLAGS= -O3 -march=pentium4 -mfpmath=sse -flto -fuse-linker-plugin 
LIBEXTRA= -c -DSOURCE
LIBLDFLAGS= ${LIBCFLAGS} -shared
LIBSOURCES=Test.cpp
LIBRARY=Test.dll

EXECFLAGS= -O3 -march=pentium4 -mfpmath=sse -flto -fuse-linker-plugin
EXTRA= -c
EXELDFLAGS= ${EXECFLAGS} -L. -lTest
SOURCES=Main.cpp
EXECUTABLE=main

LIBOBJECTS=$(LIBSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(LIBRARY) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(LIBRARY): $(LIBOBJECTS) 
    $(LD) $(LIBLDFLAGS) $(LIBOBJECTS) -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(LD) $(EXELDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): CFLAGS := $(EXECFLAGS) $(EXTRA)
$(LIBOBJECTS): CFLAGS := $(LIBCFLAGS) $(LIBEXTRA)

.cpp.o:
    @echo "...  Making: $@"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    - del /f /q *.o
    - del /f /q *.dll
    - del /f /q *.exe
```

Comment: not related to LTO - but why don't you use double include protection macro in Test.h?

Comment: Have you used Dependency Walker on the DLL to check the symbols?

Comment: Did you try to declare the destructor in `Test` also virtual (which it should be anyway)?

Comment: @Iuri Covalisin - How is it not related to LTO? It may also be worth mentioning that removing the `DECLSPEC` also makes it compile and work with LTO enabled.
@Raxvan I have looked with dependency walker, the symbols are there. The link time optimizer just can't seem to see it.
@g-makulik declaring any type of destructor in `Test` makes it work.